# atomic way of deploying website updates?

Tags: web-deployment, atomic, swap, file-rename, updating

When uploading changed files to a live webserver, how do I enforce at any given moment, my *entire* file set is either in the old state, or new, but never something in between?

With 'in between' I mean some files old and some new, or some particular file being overwritten halfway, et cetera.

Suppose I have a directory called `foo/` on my live webserver containing a framework or bunch of script files including eachother, and I need to replace a whole bunch of files **at the same time**. I'd call this an 'atomic update'.

The closest I can get is uploading my new `foo/` directory (containing the new files) to a different name, e.g. `bar/`, and then on a shell on the webserver I do:

`mv foo foo-old; mv bar foo;`

But this way there is still a *tiny* fraction of a second where `foo/` doesn't exist, when the old dir has just been renamed and the new dir is about to.

Is there a 100% correct way of doing this? I guess I need some sort of 'atomic swap', to rename or swap two directory names as a single, atomic action on file system level.

In case it's OS dependent: I'm using a webserver running CentOS and got SSH access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Near-atomic

The simplest way to achieve a *near-atomic* change of directories is to use a symbolic link as your web root, which you can re-point to a different location when upgrading.

```
$ mkdir old
$ mkdir new
$ ln -s old live
$ ls -l
live -> old
new
old
```

...

```
$ ln -snf new live
live -> new
new
old
```

Changing the target of a symbolic link is actually a 2 step operation internally, `unlink` followed by `symlink`.

### Atomic

An atomic change of directories can be achieved by creating a secondary symbolic link which points to a new directory, and then renaming the new symbolic link into the old symbolic link.

```
$ mkdir old new
$ ln -s old live
$ ln -s new live_new
$ mv -fT live_new live
```

`mv` command will use a single atomic operation (`rename`) to overwrite the old symbolic link with a new one.

### Network layer atomic

Use 2 separate hosts (physical or virtual) and route every new user from a defined moment in time to a new host which contains the upgraded website.